# Inconsistent timestamps w/ and w/o timezone when running in Jupyterlab and in Python REPL

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to understand the timestamp of timezone naive datetime in Python. I guess the timezone naive datetime may has the same timestamp with the UTC datetime witht the same digits.

First I test it in jupyterlab (Pycharm):

[image]

They have the same timestamp number.

Then I test it in Python interpreter directly:

[image]

Strange things happening - **the timestamps are now different**! This time the datetime with no timezone is in fact my local time (Australia/Sydney). I verified it here:

[image]

This is confusing.

- **Why do the Jupyterlab and Python interpreter have different
  behaviours on this?**

Just realized my jupyter is running in a docker container and the timezone in the container is UTC.

```
(base) root@2ddb91b80e47:~# date
Sun Jul  3 06:42:44 UTC 2022
```

- **What kind of timestamp should it be when
  assigning no timezone info for a datetime?**

Comment: Naive datetime objects are assumed to represent local time, i.e. the time zone your machine is configured to use. If that's not UTC, the datetime is *converted* to UTC before calculating Unix time. Therefore the differences you observe.

Comment: Thanks @FObersteiner. So Naive datetime object is basically the local datetime numbers without timezone info...

Comment: Exactly. That might be convenient in some cases - however, if you need consistent output, I'd use aware datetime whenever possible.